# Excluding paths in grep

Tags: grep, regex

I can't seem to find any documentation dealing with this: is there any way to stop grep from printing the path to the file of a matched line when searching over multiple files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> -h, --no-filename
>   Suppress the prefixing of filenames on output when multiple
>   files are searched.

Usage:

```
grep -h 'search term' multiple files
```

Example:

```
$ grep network apache2 svnserve sudo 
apache2:# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
apache2:# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
svnserve:# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
svnserve:# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
$ grep -h network apache2 svnserve sudo
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 switches to **grep** that can help you here

- **--exclude**, here you can directly provide file-names/paths to excluded using wildcard characters ( & escaping the actually required wildcard character)

  *example:* grep a ./* --exclude=*.log
- **--exclude-from**, here you can provide a filename containing those strings to be matched and excluded

I'm using *GNU grep 2.5.4*, in case it's not available using your grep version.